# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' - NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

Tengo un problema al ejecutar mi proyecto de nativescript desde un avd configurado desde android studio, ejecuto el comando **tns debug android --no-hmr** y me sale el siguiente error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
> AAPT: error: resource style/AppThemeBase21 (aka com.aeroviajespacifico.viajesilisto:style/AppThemeBase21) not found.
> error: failed linking references.
> Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

estuve investigando por la web y según mi investigación este error se ocasiona por el gradle en android lo que hice fue actualizarlo, tambien actualice el emulador, android studio como tal y ninguno funciono, a continuación anexaré los archivos de gradle:

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

el emulador solo lo tengo configurado para hacer debug a mi proyecto y revisar que todo el código funcione correctamente.

por parte de nativescript este es mi app.gradle:

```
// Add your native dependencies here:

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
//dependencies {
//  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
//}

android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    // ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

    //override supported platforms
    // ndk {
    //       abiFilters.clear()
    //          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        // }
  
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
} 

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}
```

el emulador lo ejecuto desde el power shell con el siguiente comando:

> emulator -avd ejemploAvd -dns-server 8.8.8.8

por cierto busque en todo mi proyecto la ruta que no encuentra y se encuentra en mi styles.xml en mi proyecto de nativescript.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="AppThemeBase29" parent="AppThemeBase21">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase29">
</style>
```

por cierto soy nuevo en nativescript y android claramente.

Comment: nativescript o typescript?

Comment: nativescript. Estoy utilizando nativescript para hacer una app para las android/ios de forma nativa desde un solo código, claro el lenguaje del código es typescript pero el framework es nativescript.